# java PrintWriter cannot be resolved

Tags: java, printwriter

I have no idea why I get the message "cannot be resolved" on out in eclipse on the 11th line

```
import java.io.*;
public class driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.print("hello");
    out.close();
    }

}
```

OK so now I have this

```
import java.io.*;
public class driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
           out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.print("hello");
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Why doesn't eclipse create a file once I close out?

Comment: The answer is variable scope, and you should move your close to a finally block. Where did you expect the output to go if you got a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @user3221287 is the file not being created ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse PrintWriter no file created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547365/eclipse-printwriter-no-file-created)

Comment: Please don't go posting the same question twice.

Comment: A file is created. You just don't know where. Try an absolute pathname to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use new try-with-resource block introduced in JDK 1.7, in this advantage is you don't need to worry about closing any resource which implements Closable Interface.

Then code will look like this:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt"))
        {

            out.print("hello");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print("file not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare your `PrintWriter` before the `try` block so it's scope isn't limited to the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would appreciate a look at the edit I made because I have no idea why a file isnt being created after the program ends