# Eclipse PrintWriter no file created

Tags: java, eclipse, printwriter

OK so now I have this

```
import java.io.*;
public class driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print("file not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.print("hello");
out.close();
}

}
```

Why doesn't eclipse create a file once I run the program?

Comment: Try refreshing your project directory view in Eclipse. F5

Comment: Refresh your package explorer view.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right directory? Eclipse makes a different directory for the binary and where the file gets run.

Comment: clean your project...

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE, REFRESH WORKED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your working directory. It may be the root folder of your project by default. You can also verify that the file is written by supplying a full path:

```
out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Temp\\output.txt");
```